# Google chart not opening on webview of Android Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-visualization

I am using phonegap to develop my android application.I want to show google chart on my page,I have used google chart api for this purpose.My javascript code is

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
>   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
>   function drawVisualization() {
>     // Create and populate the data table.
>     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>     var raw_data = [['Austria', 1336060, 1538156, 1576579, 1600652, 1968113, 1901067],
>                     ['Bulgaria', 400361, 366849, 440514, 434552, 393032, 517206],
>                     ['Denmark', 1001582, 1119450, 993360, 1004163, 979198, 916965],
>                     ['Greece', 997974, 941795, 930593, 897127, 1080887, 1056036]];
>
>     var years = [2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008];
>
>     data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
>     for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
>       data.addColumn('number', raw_data[i][0]);
>     }
>
>     data.addRows(years.length);
>
>     for (var j = 0; j < years.length; ++j) {
>       data.setValue(j, 0, years[j].toString());
>     }
>     for (var i = 0; i  < raw_data.length; ++i) {
>       for (var j = 1; j  < raw_data[i].length; ++j) {
>         data.setValue(j-1, i+1, raw_data[i][j]);
>       }
>     }
>
>     // Create and draw the visualization.
>     new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
>         draw(data,
>              {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
>               width:600, height:400,
>               vAxis: {title: "Year"},
>               hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
>         );
>   }
> </script>
>   </head><body>
> <div id="visualization"></div>
>   </body>
>   </html>
> ```

This is not opening the chart on my webview...
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it.My emulator does not support SVG. Thats why it is not showing the chart.